# How can I put heading and button at the top of the table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[How can I set my heading "Setting" at the top of the tableview and button "Done" on the right top?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImzOZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put them above the tableView so that they appear, and work, as part of the table, but they don't need to be  tableView elements.